# Error Could not load file or assembly 'Nlog, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=5120e14c030593c'

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a 2 Sharepoint projects Sharepoint-Svr-App & Sharepoint-svr-Job in one solution and both projects have the NLog reference. Publishing those two projects generates the corresponding *.wsp files without any issue. When I deploy the solution, Sharepoint-svr-App gets deployed without any issue but Sharepoint-Svr-Job failes with Error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Nlog, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=5120e14c030593c'
```

Please find the attached screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DsA0.png)

Entries inside Sharepoint-Srv-App.csproj are given below:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="NLog">
      <HintPath>packages\NLog.4.4.5\lib\net45\NLog.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="NLog.Web">
      <HintPath>packages\NLog.Web.4.4.0\lib\net35\NLog.Web.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>    
<ItemGroup>
```

and Sharepoint-Srv-Job.csproj looks like

```
<ItemGroup>      
    <Reference Include="NLog">      
      <HintPath>..\Sharepoint-Svr-App\packages\NLog.4.4.5\lib\net45\NLog.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="NLog.Web">
      <HintPath>..\Sharepoint-Svr-App\packages\NLog.Web.4.4.0\lib\net35\NLog.Web.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
<ItemGroup>
```

packages.config file in both projects is same like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="NLog" version="4.4.5" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NLog.Config" version="4.4.5" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NLog.Schema" version="4.4.5" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NLog.Web" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Comment: My guess is that nlog dll is not part of your manifest so it's not being deployed to GAC or bin directory of your web application. Can you show yours' manifest xml?

Comment: I think, in Packages.config has another version of Nlog dll. You are referencing 4.0.0.0 dll but, in packages.config has 4.4.5 version. That might be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got resolved

Try to add your external dlls into your solution and check.

Go to your Package.package->Advanced.

Here is one thread for your reference.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7642b88a-4046-4429-a9d2-e2088c86f3fd/deploying-custom-dlls-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointadmin